# Javascript Google Signin uncaught exception [object Object]

Tags: javascript, exception, flask, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am developing an application with flask and I have to use google sign in.
I have followed the indications at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in and they work nicely at my desktop.

But when I try it on my laptop I get the following exception: uncaught exception [object Object]

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g22Lm.png)

This is the code I am executing:

main.py:

```
"""
Flask test
"""
from flask import Flask, url_for, request, render_template, redirect
app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route("/") 
def test():
    return render_template("ejemplo.html")

#LAUNCH APP
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

ejemplo.html:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<meta name="google-signin-client_id"
content="MYGOOGLEUSERSTRINGID.apps.googleusercontent.com">

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>

<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}

function signOut() {
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
auth2.signOut().then(function () {
  console.log('User signed out.');
});
}

</script>
```

On my laptop, when I click the Google Signin button, a window emerges asking for credentials. But after giving the credentials nothing happens, the onSignIn function does not execute.

If I erase the

```
<div class="g-signin2" ...</div>
```

line, this exception does not launch.

I have also tried this in another desktop with a fresh installation of flask and its requirements but it works properly and I do not get this exception. I have used the same installation methods in the three computers:

Using the script instalar_flask.txt in https://github.com/pablopenna/flask_app

EDIT: I forgot to say that I edited /etc/hosts file to add the line

```
127.0.0.1    dominioppr.com
```

since that is the URI I have allowed in the Google API console.

EDIT2: 
I just created another user on my laptop, installed flask and executed the exact same code. This time it worked.

I suppose this problem is due to some local misconfiguration. I have had my unity/compiz desktop environment broken and I had to install a light version of gnome with metacity to get my GUI back to work, but some things did not appear to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. It was due to some misconfiguration in my user environment. I have create another user on my laptop and now the google sign in works.